# Python Script with HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, pandas, xmlhttprequest, urllib

This code is to get some images from the URL stored in the excel file. The code is also to save them but when I ran the code, I got this error "HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request".
What can I do to solve the problem?

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request

def url_to_jpg(i, url, file_Path):

    filename = 'image_{}.jpg'.format(i)
    full_path = '{}{}'.format(file_Path, filename)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)

    print('{} saved.'.format(filename))
    return None

File_Name = 'Cooler_URL_2.xlsx'
File_Path = 'images/'

#reading the file as pandas dataframe
urls = pd.read_excel(File_Name)

#save file as directory
for i, url in enumerate(url_values):
    url_to_jpg(i, url[0], File_Path)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the most common cause of a 400 Bad Request Error is simply inputting an incorrect URL. Domain names (e.g. abc.com) are case-insensitive, meaning that this mixed case link to ABC.COM works just as well as the normal, lowercase version of abc.com.

Comment: Do not just summarize other answers in your answer. Answers should address the issue raised in the question - for merely incidental clarifications you are free to use comments.

Comment: Is it possible I get this message if the URL are encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

this below line 

`for i, url in enumerate(url_values):
    url_to_jpg(i, url[0], File_Path)`

to be replaced by

`for i, url in enumerate(url_values):
    url_to_jpg(i, url, File_Path)`